# Icon on tabs not working

Tags: android, icons, android-tabs

the icons on my tabs is not showing how i wanted them to be. I wanted the to be icons from my drawable folders but when I'm calling it. It returns numbers not icons.
Here is my code.

```
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return ""+R.drawable.car2;
            case 1:
                return "Pending Cars";
            case 2:
                return "Currently Rented";
            case 3:
                return "Drivers";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

the `return  ""+R.drawable.car2;` suppose to return me an icon if I'm not mistaken right? But it returns me `2130837582`. Thanks for the help sirs. :)

Comment: Are you using any 3 party library for tab?

Comment: R.drawable.car2 is return the number , which is ID of drawable .....

Comment: @Nithinlal no sir. Just the template from the android studio.

Comment: @sushildlh - ohhh, so. So how can I return the drawable itself sir?

Comment: icon cannot set in the adapter . You have set the icon separate

Answer (score 0):

`R.drawable.car2` - is not an icon - it's resource ID and it's `int`. You should use this ID to get icon drawable from resources:

```
Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.car2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 tablayout= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
 tablayout.addTab(tablayout.newTab().setText().setIcon(R.drawable.icon1));
 tablayout.addTab(tablayout.newTab().setText().setIcon(R.drawable.icon2));
 tablayout.addTab(tablayout.newTab().setText().setIcon(R.drawable.icon3));
```